# C# Get mails AFTER a specified date using Microsoft.Exchange.WebSercvices EWS

Tags: c#, query-string, exchangewebservices

I'm using the EWS to download mails. As the mailbox is quite large, I'd like to filter the mails with the querystring. I found a method to only download mails of a specified date using `Received:20/11/2019` but

1. This is not returning all the mails from this date (why - it seems, that only unread mails with attachments are part of the results)
2. I'd like to get all mails from 20 Nov. 2019 and later

Here is my code:

```
    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService exchange = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
    exchange.Credentials = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WebCredentials("User", "********", "Domain");
    exchange.AutodiscoverUrl("Name@domain.com");
    string QString = "Recieved:20/11/2019";

    if (exchange != null)
    {
        Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FindItemsResults<Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item> Results = exchange.FindItems(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, QString, new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(100));

        foreach(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item MI in Results)
        {
            /*Print subject to command window*/
            System.Console.WriteLine(MI.Subject);
        }
    }
```

I found an answer here, but its PHP and I'm not really skilled in it:
[Getting emails after a specific date with php-ews (Exchange Web Services)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762337/getting-emails-after-a-specific-date-with-php-ews-exchange-web-services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, SearchFilter does work well for me:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter SF = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, new System.DateTime(2019,11,20));
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FindItemsResults<Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item> Results = exchange.FindItems(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, SF, new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(100));
```